# Is there an in-built support to add epsilon as an input parameter for double comparsions with mvel dialect?

Tags: java, double, drools, mvel, epsilon

I am using mvel dialect for defining rules for drools rule engine. It may comprise of arithmetic expressions like in the when part as shown below

```
rule "Test rule"
    dialect "mvel"
when
    context : ActionContext( context.get("test") == 0.8 )
then
context.add("Success" , "test");

end
```

I want the execution of rules to consider an epsilon value whenever there is a double comparison. As far as i went through the mvel library and internet search space i couldnt find a straightforward solution. But this seems like a common problem. Does mvel support this feature in any way?

Note : i don't want to use BigDecimal considering the performance implications.

Something i can do is write a custom function for every double comparison. But this seems like the last thing to do. Is there a better way?

Comment: You'd do it the same way you'd do it in Java. If you're avoiding BigDecimal, that would be a custom function, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes but mvel is designed to handle type conversion and to be elegant right, if I add a function call everywhere, it kinda removes the advantage of using mvel. Thats why I am checking if there is a way to enforce mvel to do it @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Maybe if you framed this as an mvel question instead of a drools question then...